# SwiftUI TextField Bug

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm having trouble with a bug in the TextField Keyboard.
When I tap the corresponding textField, the Keyboard appears, but something like a white View appears together and the TextField is hidden. (See image)
Xcode12 Iphone11-Ios13.5 Simulator doesn't have this bug, but Ios14 does. Does anyone know a solution?

```
struct PlaceholderTextField: View {
    var placeholderTxt: String
    var keyboardType: UIKeyboardType?
    @Binding var text: String

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                VStack {
                    if self.keyboardType != nil {
                        TextField(self.placeholderTxt, text: $text)
                            .autocapitalization(.none)
                            .padding(20)
                            .keyboardType(self.keyboardType!)
                    } else {
                        TextField(self.placeholderTxt, text: $text)
                            .autocapitalization(.none)
                            .padding(20)
                    }
                }
                .background(Color.white)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
                .padding()
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @ObservedObject(initialValue: LoginViewModel()) var loginController: LoginViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
    @State var emailLogin: Bool = true
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
    @Binding var rootIsActive: Bool

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            GeometryReader { bodyView in
                ZStack {
                    Color.backgroundColor.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        SwitchAccountIDButton(emailLogin: self.$emailLogin)
                        self.userIdTextField
                        self.passwordTextField
                        Button(action: {
                            self.userData.isLoading = true
                            if self.emailLogin {
                                self.loginController.singin(self.loginController.email, self.loginController.password, self.emailLogin)
                            } else {
                                self.loginController.singin(self.loginController.phoneNumber, self.loginController.password, self.emailLogin)
                            }
                        }) {
                            ButtonView(title: "ログイン", fontColor: .white, bgColor: Color.primaryColor, width: bodyView.size.width * 0.9)
                                .accessibility(identifier: "login_login_button")
                        }
                        NavigationLink(destination: ReissuePassword(shouldPopToRootView: self.$rootIsActive)) {
                            Text("パスワードを忘れた場合")
                                .underline()
                                .foregroundColor(Color.primaryColor)
                                .padding(.top)
                        }.isDetailLink(false)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("ログイン")
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }, label: { Text("キャンセル").foregroundColor(Color.primaryColor).fontWeight(.regular) })
            })
        }
    }
    var userIdTextField: some View {
        VStack {
            if self.emailLogin {
                PlaceholderTextField(placeholderTxt: "メールアドレス",keyboardType: .default ,text: self.$loginController.email)
                    .accessibility(identifier: "login_mailaddress_textfield")
            } else {
                PlaceholderTextField(placeholderTxt: "電話番号", keyboardType: .phonePad, text: self.$loginController.phoneNumber)
                    .accessibility(identifier: "login_phonenumber_textfield")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]   [image]